# update data set after extracting features from face in python using pickle

Tags: python, pickle, face-recognition

I am new in python and following this article https://www.mygreatlearning.com/blog/face-recognition/#whatsopencv to extract features from face. After trying it, I realise that I do looping inside directory `Images` for each image and then save it inside `face_enc`:

```
datas = {"encodings": knownEncodings, "names": knownNames}
f = open("face_enc", "wb")
f.write(pickle.dumps(datas))
f.close()
```

So, the thing that makes me confused is, let's say that I have 50 images inside `Images` directory then I add another 100 images (just for example), so I will do looping from the start (1-150 images) and then save it in `face_enc`. Is there a way to update data inside `face_enc` without saving it from the start to saving time?